# was clearTimeout successful?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check of clearTimeout was successful.

I have a javascript function which is run at an interval of 30 seconds asynchronously. It is a self calling function and uses setTimeout() to repeat itself in a loop. In a particular case, I need to call this function after some event occurs. Hence I first clearTimeout and call the function again. But I don't know whether I was able to successfully clear the previous loop or have I started two separate loops now. Can I do something like this? :

```
if(clearTimeout(timer))
alert("cleared");
```

Comment: If you passed the correct parameter, you have cleared the loop. But if you want to feel safer, consider passing another argument to the function that is `true` or `false`; if `false`, the function should not set up the loop.

Comment: I feel as though there should be a nice way to track the state of your timer and always feel confident your clearTimeout was successful. Here is a simple fiddle to get people started. http://jsfiddle.net/ASYgU/

Comment: @mrtsherman umm, i tried fiddling a bit with the code; outputted the value of the variable timer. Turns out, it is some number which increments. One thing's for sure: the `if(timer)` statement will always return true and cannot be used to check if the timer is running. But it can be used to track how many times the loop was run. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roopunk/ASYgU/4/)

Answer (score 5):

> *"Is there a way to check of clearTimeout was successful."*

No, there's no state maintained that you can check, but if you manage your timers properly, it shouldn't be an issue.

---

You could create your own stateful timer object I suppose...

```
var _slice = Array.prototype.slice;

  // substitute for setTimeout
function myTimer(fn,ms) {
    var args = _slice.call(arguments,2),
        timer_state = {
            complete: false,
            timer: setTimeout(function() {
                timer_state.complete = true;
                fn.apply(this, args);
            }, ms)
        };
    return timer_state;
};

  // substitute for clearTimeout
function clearMyTimer(timer_obj) {
    timer_obj.complete = true;
    clearTimeout(timer_obj.timer);
};
```

Example of clearing the timer...

```
  // create a timer
var timer = myTimer( function() {
    console.log('timer is done');
}, 1000);

console.log( timer.complete ); // complete? false

clearMyTimer( timer ); // clear it

console.log( timer.complete ); // complete? true
```

Example of letting it run...

```
  // create a timer
var timer = myTimer( function() {
    console.log('timer is done');
}, 1000);

console.log( timer.complete ); // complete? false

  // check the timer object after it has expired
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log( timer.complete ); // complete? true
}, 1500);
```

---

*EDIT: Updated to make `this` consistent in strict mode, and to support additional argument passed through to the callback. Thanks to [@Saxoier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/798880/saxoier) for the note.*

Comment: `myTimer` will break if you run the code in a strict environment (`'use strict'`) and use `this` in the function. In addition passed arguments after the delay-arg will be ignored. Additional arguments might be standardized in HTML 5 - already implemented in Firefox, Chrome and Opera but can easily be implemented in environments that don't support it. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3p8T/)

Comment: @Saxoier: Good points. I updated. Applied the extra args directly to the callback instead of the `setTimeout`, so the args will work in typically unsupported browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is state using a closure. Its quite straight forward.

To ensure you are not calling it again and again as you say, you can try something like this...

```
// declare only once, singleton concept using closure
(function() { 
    var timerReference, 
    timerMethod = function(fn) {
        fn();
        if (timerReference) {
            window.clearTimeout(timerReference);
        }
        timerReference = window.setTimeout(function() {
           timerMethod(fn);
        }, 30000);
    };
    window.doTimer = function(fn) {
        timerMethod(fn);
    };
})();

// you can call this as many times as you like
doTimer(function() {
    alert('hi');
});
doTimer(function() {
    alert('hi again');
});
```

In this case it calling doTimer() will destroy the previous one before it so you will always have only one timer going at one time.

I can also code one that will queue them up and wait for the last one to complete but that is another writeup.